# Not loading the whole object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

```
public class Subscription implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id_subscription;
    private Contact contact;
    // ...

    public Subscription (Contact contact, ...) {
        this.contact = contact;
        ...
    }
    // ...
```

Now i have just the `id_contact` so I have to load the whole object `Contact`

```
Contact contact = contact_resposetory.findOne(id_contact);

Subscription subscription = new  Subscription( contact , ...);
// ...
subscription_resposetory.save(subscription );
```

My question is there is not a solution that we can use directly just the primary key of `Contact` instead of loading the whole object ? because in Database in `Subscription`'s table the is just a `id_contact` as `FK`.

Comment: it is not very clear: are you trying to get only a Contact attribute or what?

Comment: i want to save my subscription object after, i update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although JPA doesn't allow it, Hibernate is much less restrictive and lets you do the following:

```
Contact contaCct = new Contact();
contact.setId(id_contact);
Subscription subscription = new  Subscription( contact , ...);
```

Hibernate will use the Contact FK and populate it on Subscription.

Comment: there is no bad hiding behavior of doing that ?

Comment: It's good from a performance point of view, when you only want to persist.